# EGit shows "up arrow" even if repository is up-to-date

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I'm using Eclipse JEE Mars and have a project under Git source control with several branches.  It has always worked perfectly, until today.

However, all of a sudden this strange thing started to happen: the icon that indicates that my local branch is some revisions ahead of the remote branch (up arrow symbol with a number near to it, next to the project name) is always visible, and the number increments at every commit, **even if everything is correctly pushed to the remote repository!**. So, basically, this is just a "cosmetic" thing, but it's annoying me to no end.

What I checked:

- The remote repository IS up to date. I checked the remote files
  manually with our server-side repo browser. Everything seems ok
- There is nothing to push. When I do a push from EGit, it tells me:
  `myBranch -> myBranch [up-to-date]`
- There is nothing to pull from the
  repo. Local and remote branch are identical

What I tried:

- Hard git reset on the branch. Nothing changed
- Right click on the project -> Replace with -> Branch, tag or reference ->  - remote branch. Nothing changed
- Restarted Eclipse. Nothing changed
- Restarted computer. Nothing changed

I'm running out of ideas... anyone can help me out?

Comment: Did you look into the config file to see that your local branch is actually tracking the branch you want it to track?

Comment: Indeed, the `.git/config` was pointing to another branch, the one I based the new branch on to be precise. Weird. Reformulate the comment as an answer if you want me to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the `.git/config` file to see if your local branch is configured to actually track the branch you want it to track.

If your local branch `foo` should track the remote-tracking branch `foo` on remote `origin` the branch configuration section should look like this:

```
[branch "foo"]
  merge = refs/heads/foo
  remote = origin
```

Comment: As a side note, when debugging Git configurations via Eclipse, one can easily view/edit system, global/user, and repository configurations via Window->Preferences->Team->Configuration.

Comment: Thanks this answer is what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: You probably have another branch that confuses Eclipse.

I had the same behaviour in my Eclipse 2018-09 and suddenly I fixed it. Let me tell you how.

I started working on a new feature 'A', then realized that's a bad name so I renamed it to 'AnotherA' (that actually makes a new branch). Now like you described every commit I made has been shown in Eclipse on this 'AnotherA' branch with the "up arrow" even that everything was up to date.

Now I knew I should get rid of branch 'A' as it serves no purpose anymore. So I checked the branch in BitBucket and after making sure everything is okay I deleted it (it said the branch has 5 commits newer than master branch but since they were also in 'AnotherA' it was no problem).

No suddenly after deleting 'A' my branch 'AnotherA' does not show this upward arrow anymore.

Sadly I can't tell you the exact solution. Maybe branch 'A' was not fully pushed to the remote repository but I did not check that.